# how to put a text in front of a clickable image

Tags: html, css

This is what my clickable image part of HTML and CSS look like:

I havent put the text anywhere but I want to put the text in front of the clickable image.
When I did try to put it in front via youtube tutorials it didnt work.
It kept going outside of the image, either on the top or bottom of the content.
Does anyone know how to put it in front of the image and for it to possibly not be clickable or have a hover like the image does?

Thanks in advance.

```css
.content_conteiner3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.content img {
  position:relative;
  margin: 5px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  filter: brightness(50%);
  opacity: 0.9;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.content a:hover img {
  filter: brightness(100%);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
  <content class="content_conteiner3">
    <div class="content">
      <a
target="_blank" onclick="ga('send','event','click','content_googlemaps')" 
href="#"> 
<img src="./jpg">

      </a>
    </div>
  </content>
```

Comment: Read about css positions and you will be able to do it and many more cool things: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, using a mixture of z-index and position. [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/2tcnf36x/1/)

### HTML

```html
<content class="content_conteiner3">
    <div class="content">
      <a
        target="_blank" onclick="ga('send','event','click','content_googlemaps')" 
        href="#"> 
          <span>Your text goes here</span>
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/kF0Avwv.png">
      </a>
    </div>
  </content>
```

### CSS

```css
.content_conteiner3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  position:relative;
}

.content img {
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  filter: brightness(50%);
  opacity: 0.9;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.content a:hover img {
  filter: brightness(100%);
  opacity: 1;
}

.content a span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events:none;
}

.content a img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  z-index:1;
}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! Been looking at tutorials for hours trying to figure out how. Thank you again

Comment: @ella make sure to accept answer if you feel this answer helped your issue ;)

Comment: Oh thank you. I just made the account and didnt realise that button was there. Thanks :)